# If condition is true then break or close sqlDatareader and get out from using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) method

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["Date"]);

        int Classroom = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ClassroomNo"]);

        TimeSpan ST = (TimeSpan)rdr["StartingTime"];
        TimeSpan ET = (TimeSpan)rdr["EndingTime"];
        TimeSpan span = ET.Subtract(ST);
        double Minutesdifference = span.TotalMinutes;

        TimeSpan NewTime = (TimeSpan)rdr["StartingTIme"];

        for (int i = 1; i <= Minutesdifference; i++)
        {
            NewTime = NewTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            // Response.Write(NewTime + "<br>");
            Response.Write(Classroom + "<br>");
            Response.Write(ClassroomNo + "<br>");
            Response.Write(dt + "<br>");
            Response.Write(dt2 + "<br>");
            Response.Write(StartTime + "<br>");
            Response.Write(NewTime + "<br>");
            Response.Write(ST + "<br>");

            if ((Classroom == ClassroomNo && dt == dt2 && StartTime == NewTime) || (Classroom == ClassroomNo && dt == dt2 && StartTime == ST))
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (flag == 0)
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("spStoreTimeSlotDetails2", con);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", hfUsername.Value);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", lblFacultyName.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dt);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", day);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ST", StartTime);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ET", EndTime);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeSlot", hfTmeSlot.Value);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Topic", txtTopic.Text);
    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClassroomNo", ClassroomNo);

    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    lblMessage.Text = "Data Saved Successfully";
}
else if (flag == 1)
{
    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lblMessage.Text = "Time Slot already allocated by some other Employee. Please choose another";
}
```

I write If Condition into for loop. If that condition is true then break the for loop but `while(rdr.Read())` method still executing. I just want to close Reader method and directly go out from `using(sqlDataReader rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader)` method and execute if(flag==0).

Comment: That is because you need to break the while loop to, use another lag which gets set in the if loop before break and then use it outside the while loop. You already have a flag been set 0 /1 , why don't you add a break in condition (flag == 1) and voila, it will come out of while loop

Comment: @shan Goto is not a very good programmatic statement to be used in C#, its normally not suggested, just supported for some sort of compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is after breaking from for loop you still want to execute the code in  the `if loop of flag`, so just add this code to break the out of `rdr.Read()` while loop

```
else if (flag == 1)
{
  lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
  lblMessage.Text = "Time Slot already allocated by some other Employee. Please choose another";
   break;
 }
```

This code will ensure that Reader object is disposed and closed:

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

So nothing much required beyond the change suggested

Comment: Great that it helped, if do not mind up voting the solution that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.Read() && !flag)
{
     ....
     for (int i = 1; i <= Minutesdifference; i++)
     {
           if ((Classroom == ClassroomNo && dt == dt2 && StartTime == NewTime) || (Classroom == ClassroomNo && dt == dt2 && StartTime == ST))
                            {
                                flag = 1;

                                break;
                            }
                           else
                           {flag=0;}
                        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Sergei Yevlakov, set flag variable to 0 before the while loop as follows.

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    flag=0;
    while (reader.Read() && !flag)
    {
          .....
           for (int i = 1; i <= Minutesdifference; i++)
           {
                    if ((Classroom == ClassroomNo && dt == dt2 && 
                    StartTime== NewTime) || (Classroom == ClassroomNo && 
                    dt == dt2 && StartTime == ST))
                    {
                            flag = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    //no need of else part here now.
                    ...
            }
    }
}
```